# run script on resume from suspend

Tags: release-freya

After resuming from suspend fan is working full speed. Running this  as sudo fixes it:
**for x in /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device*/cur_state; do  echo 0 > $x;.**

Where should I put the hook script in order to run on resume? I tried **/lib/systemd/system-sleep** and **/etc/pm/sleep.d** to no avail.

Comment: The answer given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226278/run-script-on-wakeup?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#_=_) by @SpmP works on Loki without installing additional packages.

Answer (score 2):

This is me answering my question: simply place the script in **/etc/pm/sleep.d** and install **pm-utils** with **sudo apt-get install pm-utils**