# Execute Script On Resume From Suspend

Tags: suspend

Using instructions from [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3087/run-script-on-resume-from-suspend) I've created and placed a script at **/etc/pm/sleep.d**:

msi-keyboard.sh:

```
msi-keyboard -m normal -c left,red,high -c middle,purple,high -c right,sky,high
```

Unfortunately, after resuming it doesn't get called. Anyone have a solution on how to execute commands or a script on resume from suspend?

P.S. I've disabled login on resume/screensaver

Answer (score 0):

Make sure script executable. It should be look like this I guess.

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    resume|thaw)
        msi-keyboard -m normal -c left,red,high -c middle,purple,high -c right,sky,high
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: I've done that, rebooted and it doesn't work after resuming from sleep.

Comment: Have you figured out how to do this? This is not working for me either.